# Pascal Triangle - Print only 'n'th line

Tags: java

Here is some code for outputting a Pascal Triangle, and it shows all of the lines of the triangle. For example, if user input is 5 then it will output as follows:

```
1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
```

I just want it to output the last line, though. So for 5, only 1 4 6 4 1. I'm having trouble accomplishing this, though it's easy enough, I know. Any help is appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PascalsTriangle {
    public static void computeRow(int n) {
       int counter;
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
               System.out.print(pascalValue(i, j) + " ");
           }
           System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static int pascalValue(int i, int j) {
        if (j == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else if (j == i) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return pascalValue(i - 1, j - 1) + pascalValue(i - 1, j);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Which line number of Pascal's Triangle? ");
        int row = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Line " +row+" of Pascal's Triangle:\n");
        computeRow(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try putting a condition before the print statement. Which condition would you use?

Comment: I've tried various if statements before the print statement in computeRow, but can't seem to find one that works as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `computeRow()` method to include a check for the particular line of the triangle which you wish to print.  In your case, you only want to print the last line, which will occur during the *last* iteration of the outer `for` loop:

```
public static void computeRow(int n) {
    int counter;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // only output the line if it be the last one
        if (i == n-1) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(pascalValue(i, j) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    computeRow(5);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Line 5 of Pascal's Triangle:
1 4 6 4 1
```

Comment: Thank you! This works well. I never thought of it like this. Thanks again, Tim.

Answer (score 0):

Why even have the outer for loop? The inner loop executes only when i = n-1. So, you could lock the value of i, that is, the row index (n), and use your recursive function like this:

```
for (int j=0; j<=n; j++) {
   System.out.print(pascalValue(n, j) + " ");
}
```

Btw, I would not advice using recursion to find the Pascal Value at a given index, I would use it instead to build up to the row index, n, and use a for loop to fill a row with the Pascal Values. This way, you use Dynamic Programming too and prevent overlaps. This is what it would like in JavaScript.

```
var getRow = function(rowIndex) {
    if (rowIndex == 0) {
      return [1];
    }
    else {
        var row = [1];
        previousLine = getRow(rowIndex - 1);
        for (let i = 0; i < previousLine.length - 1; i++) {
          row.push(previousLine[i] + previousLine[i + 1]);
        }
        row.push(1);
    } 
    return row;
};
```